# Rikulo Bootjack Dart modal window not working on android devices

Tags: html, dart, rikulo, bootjack

I'm building a webapp with Dart and I've used Rikulo's Bootjack library to get some Bootstrap elements. I have two modal windows in my app.

One of them is lanunched by triggering a button so I just had to follow the examples:

https://github.com/rikulo/bootjack/tree/master/example

I want the other one to be launched only on certain situations, so I've coded the following:

```
Modal myWindow;
DivElement readComplete = querySelector('#readComplete');

myWindow = new Modal(readComplete);
myWindows.show();
```

I've notice that both windows works fine in Desktop environments, but I've not been able to run the second way on Android Devices. I've tested with Chrome, Chrome Beta and Firefox. Does anyone has an idea of what may be going on? Is this a library or device restriction or I am doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you test with [latest Dart SDK](http://gsdview.appspot.com/dart-archive/channels/dev/raw/latest/)? It fixed a few dart2js bugs.

Comment: Running Dart Editor version 1.3.0.dev_07_10 (DEV). The problem persists :(

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Sorry for the trouble guys, but finally it wasn't related with bootjack. There was a different behavior between mobile and desktop solution when calling the 'route' library to use a Websocket. That was causing the show method not to be called due to an exception, but only on the mobile version. That is why I didn't see it when debugging from dart editor.